# LINQ to XML query returning no results

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm doing some XLINQ in VB for work. I basically need to pull some values from a small chunk of XML as listed here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Fields>
    <typeQtyRadioButtonList>1</typeQtyRadioButtonList>
    <cmbQtyCheck>Reject</cmbQtyCheck>
    <optHaulierDetCheck>1</optHaulierDetCheck>
    <txtReasonCode>1</txtReasonCode>
    <optGenMod>0</optGenMod>
    <optFarmRestrictions>0</optFarmRestrictions>
    <cmbFRAction>Reject</cmbFRAction>
    <optDisease>0</optDisease>
    <txtDReasonCode>2</txtDReasonCode>
    <optWithdrawl>0</optWithdrawl>
    <txtWithdrawl>3</txtWithdrawl>
    <optABM>0</optABM>
    <txtCompliance>3</txtCompliance>
    <optForm>1</optForm>
  </Fields>
```

And to do this I am using:

```
    Dim _ControlValueCollections = From _ControlValueCollection In _Xmlx.Descendants("Fields") _
                                  Select _Qstn1Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("typeQtyRadioButtonList").Value, _
                                         _Qstn2Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optHaulierDetCheck").Value, _
                                         _Qstn3Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optGenMod").Value, _
                                         _Qstn4Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optFarmRestrictions").Value, _
                                         _Qstn5Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optDisease").Value, _
                                         _Qstn6Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optWithdrawl").Value, _
                                         _Qstn7Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optABM").Value, _
                                         _Qstn8Response = _ControlValueCollection.Element("optForm").Value

    For Each _ControlValueCollection In _ControlValueCollections
```

... Leaving out the implementation of the For Each loop....

So I have stuck a break point on the for each and the collection has no elements in it. Am I missing something ?

EDIT: The Answer was of course that I was using an XElement and not an XDocument.

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize `_Xmlx'? Is that an XElement or XDocument?

Comment: @ Martin Honnen: Above that but it uses NDA Code so i can't show it, it is an XElement. which I have just found out does not work. It needs to be an XDocument right? Stick the reason for that in an answer and I'll give you the green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Xmlx.Descendants("Fields")` looks for descendant elements named `Fields` of the XContainer `_Xmlx`. If you have done `XDocument _Xmlx = XDocument("input.xml");` then your XContainer `_Xmlx` has a sole descendant element named `Fields` and your code would work. If you have done `XElement _Xmlx = XElement.Load("input.xml");` then the variable `_Xmlx` is the "Fields" element itself.

Comment: Cheers, that makes perfect sense!